# Change assembly opcode

Tags: assembly, hex, opcode, ida

I have the following code:
[image]

I am using IDA PRO. I am trying to patch this code and change the line 
mov eax, [rax+10h] to mov eax, 3.
mov eax, 3 is B8 03 00.

I do this in the hex editor and when I change the code from

**8B 40 10** 8D 48 01 41 89 4B 10 EB 05 B8 01 00 00

to

**B8 03 00** 8D 48 01 41 89 4B 10 EB 05 B8 01 00 00

I get **B8 03 00 8D 48** in the same line which is a different command than what i intended.

what am i doing wrong? how can i make this change?

[image]

Comment: This is a 64-bit program, the assembler between your ears is running in 16-bit mode.

Comment: it is 64bit but i do not understand your reply. what should i do to make it "mov eax, 3" instead of the current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the machine codes for `mov *a*, 3` in 64-bit mode:

```
mov eax, 3:  b8 03 00 00 00
mov  ax, 3:  66 b8 03 00
mov  al, 3:  b0 03
```

As you can see `mov eax, 3` needs **5** bytes. You can try:

```
6a 03    push 3
58       pop rax
```

But you'll get trouble with the following instruction `lea ecx, [rax+1]`!

Comment: +1, but remove the last line.  The following `lea` instruction does not dereference.